# How to dynamically add a textbox and set a unique v-model in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vuejs2

So let's start with my code:

```
<button v-on:click="addTextbox">Add</button>

<div id="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
        <input id="full_name" type="text" v-model="full_name">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So that is basically the code. It outputs a single textbox and what I wanted to do is whenever I click on the **Add** button, it will automatically generate that whole html (from `<div class="row">` to `</div>`).

So I researched and tried this:

```
addTextbox: function() {
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "text";
   container.appendChild(input);
}
```

It adds a textbox but I have problems here:

First is that it only creates a new textbox but I need it to create the whole row div.

Second is that I want each textbox to have a unique `v-model`. For example the first one is `v-model="full_name"` and when I add a new one, it should be like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
        <input id="full_name" type="text" v-model="full_name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
        <input id="full_name2" type="text" v-model="full_name2">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the right way to do it in vue.js.

for dynamic rows, i would have loop through an array like this:

```
<button v-on:click="addRow">Add</button>

<div id="container">

  <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
      <input type="text" value="{{row.full_name}}">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

rows = [{full_name: "john doe"}, {full_name: "jane doe"}]

addRow: function() {
  this.rows.push({full_name: ""});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will allow a unique v-model for each input.  It creates an array of inputs, so you can add as many as you want.  The addRow function dynamically adds them and the v-if on the button removes the button when all of the inputs have been displayed.  You'll have to make it pretty though!

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-if="currentInputIndex < inputs.length" v-on:click="addRow">Add</button>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
      <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
        <input type="text" :name="row.inputname" v-model="row.inputvalue">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

And the js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentInputIndex: 0,
    inputs: [ 'fullname', 'email'],
    rows: []
  }, 
  methods: {
    addRow: function() {
      this.rows.push({inputname: this.inputs[this.currentInputIndex], inputvalue: ""});
      this.currentInputIndex++;
    }
  }
});
```